# servicestack ormlite postgres connection timeout

Tags: postgresql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

From release 1.0.41 have some issue with ormlite. Connection takes long time and expires but command itself is executed.
I also tried to use 1.0.42 but it is same issue.

```
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql">
  <Version>3.2.2</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Core">
  <Version>1.0.42</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL.Core">
  <Version>1.0.42</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Server.Core">
  <Version>1.0.42</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

that is the only packages is used. Any breaking changes in latest release?
1.0.42 should be minor fixes, right?!

Comment: There aren't breaking changes, the major change is that we've moved to the new msbuild vs2017 build system which is now generating both .NET 4.5 and .NET Core builds. This snippet isn't useful, can you include stand-alone sample code which behaves differently under older version of ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL.Core and current version which we can run locally to see the issue?

Comment: Looks like it was smth related to the way async works. All is fine and ServiceStack works as it should work. Thanks for quick responses. ServiceStack is awesome project!!! Thanks for your work!